# How do I build the Rust standard library with a custom musl?

Tags: build, rust, musl

I want to build static Rust executables with a customized version of musl. As a first step, I'm making myself familiar with Rust's build system.

I took the slightly outdated [`docker-rust-musl`](https://github.com/fzgregor/docker-rust-musl) GitHub project and updated URLs that went out-of-date. Everything seems to work well with the build, but when I want to compile with `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` the compiler doesn't find the musl `std` crate:

```
root@beb234fba4af:/build# cat example.rs
fn main() { println!("hi!"); panic!("failed"); }

root@beb234fba4af:/build# rustc --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl example.rs
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
  |
  = note: the `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` target may not be installed

error: aborting due to previous error
```

In fact, `/usr/local/lib/rustlib/` only contains the `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` directory, even though output during the build indicates that `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` is built:

```
[...]
Building stage2 std artifacts (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -> x86_64-unknown-linux-musl)
[...]
```

However, when it comes to the installation step `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` is nowhere to be seen:

```
[...]
Install std stage2 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
install: creating uninstall script at /usr/local/lib/rustlib/uninstall.sh
install: installing component 'rust-std-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'

    std is standing at the ready.

Install rustc stage2 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
install: creating uninstall script at /usr/local/lib/rustlib/uninstall.sh
install: installing component 'rustc'

    Rust is ready to roll.

Build completed in 0:31:07
```

What do I have to do to install the `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` Rust standard library?

**Progress:**

Digging through the build environment revealed that `make all` builds the Rust `std` library with `musl` but the subsequent `make install` step does not install it.
We have a [temporary fix](https://github.com/fzgregor/docker-rust-musl/commit/e82d24e07f43a70de4a22dc6a2bf676d4187f196) in the `build.sh` script of the previously mentioned docker image. 
It is unclear whether that is an issue of the build environment or of its usage.

The issue is [known](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/39235) to the Rust developers. No eta of the fix, however.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but since all you want to do is to build a static executable might want to just check out https://github.com/clux/muslrust instead.

Comment: This image uses `rustup` to install a pre-compiled version of the rust std library compiled with musl which you can use then to statically compile rust applications. I want to build static rust applications with my customized version of musl.